# Memory mapped point to pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, microcontroller

My C is pretty rusty, but I'm wondering if I'g on the right track with my understanding of the following syntax.(this is in a io header file)

```
#define TCC0 (*(TC0_t*) 0x8000)

TCC0      TC0_t
[ • ] --→ [ • ] --→ [xxxx xxx] 0x8000
```

- [ • ] = pointer
- TC0_t is a structure, here is basically what the structure definition looks like.

  ```
  typedef struct TC0_struct
  {
      ...
  }TC0_t;
  ```

So my assumption is TCC0 is pointing to a structure pointer that is pointing to a memory address that corresponds to the timer register on my microcontroller.

If this is true if I wanted to create my own structure for multiple timers would myTimer structure look something like

```
typedef struct myTimer
{
    TC0_t    *timer;
    //other useful stuff
 }myTimer;

myTimer Xtimer;
xtimer.timer = TCD0;
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

So holt suggested adding more to what I want to do with myTimer. Essentially I would have different timers corresponding to different ports this would be in the io header file

```
#define TCC0 (*(TC0_t*) 0x8000)
#define TCD0 (*(TC0_t*) 0x9000)
```

I want to create a structure that would allow me easily cycle through the timers, similar to a cycling through tasks in a tasklist. I may be overthinking this.

Comment: I'm using an Xmega32C4, and you are correct I am missing a parenthesis.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have already checked this, or if it helps at all, but here is the [atmel application note on using xmega timer/counters](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8045.pdf).  What are you using the timer for?  Regularly scheduled execution of code?  It looks like a single timer (hardware, eg TCx0) can have multiple 'channels' for associated functionality.

Comment: .... or external signaling of hardware?  Further reading... It looks like there are 2 timers Timer0 and Timer1 which can be mapped to 4 ports [D-F]. TCC0 corresponds to Timer0 on Port C.  Trying to wrap my head around the goal you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to cycle through timers, for a capacitive sensor slider switch. I know there is libraries out there for it but I'm being stubborn. Anyways I want to be able to cycle through timers, turning one on at a time. Each timer would be connected to an ISR that would toggle a pin.

Comment: One note from the [xmega d4 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8135-8-and-16-bit-avr-microcontroller-atxmega16d4-32d4-64d4-128d4_datasheet.pdf) (page 54) it looks like these should be 0x0800 and 0x0900 for TCC0 and TCD0 respectively.  Also, an interesting note on page 51 (port C alternate functions) -- it looks like configuring TC0 as TC2 can allow all 8 pins of port C to be used as PWM output.  Not necessarily useful for cycling, but also on that page it looks like a single timer can control 4 pins (maybe not asynchronously).

Comment: I'm using C4, but yes the timers on PORTC and PORTD have 4 channels per timer0 and 2 for timer1. I think i need to do some more reading on how to pass structures to functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're wrong, there is only one pointer, and one dereference operator, the first one is a cast operator. The code can be seen like that:

```
TC0_t *ptc0 = 0x8000 ; // Pointer pointing to the '0x8000 address'
TC0_t TCC0 = *ptc0 ; // Value at the '0x8000 address'
```

If it is what you have understood, then your question is not really clear...

In your example, if `TCD0` is same as `TCC0`, then your code is wrong because `TCC0` is an instance of `TC0_t` not `TC0_t*`. If `TCD0` is not `TCC0` then maybe explain what it is.

By the way, be careful with naming convention: If you don't want to use caml case starting with uppercase for struct, at least do not start your variable with an uppercase letter, it could be really misleading for anyone wanting to understand your code.

Comment: hmm, so TCD0 and TCC0 would located at different ports so there is a #define for each

    #define TCD0 (*(TC0_t*) 0x9000)
    #define TCC0 (*(TC0_t*) 0x8000)

dose that make it more or less clear?

Comment: @Lpaulson Maybe you should add information in your answer, do you currently have different timers TCC0 and TCD0? And you want to create a struct that could store any of the timers? All timers?

Answer (score 2):

There is only one pointer here. The first * is a pointer dereference.

When defined like this:

```
#define TCC0 (*(TC0_t*) 0x8000)
```

`TCC0` means:

- Take integer `0x8000`.
- Convert it to a pointer to `TC0_t`.
- Access value under that pointer.

`TCC0` behaves kinda like regular variable of type `TC0_t`. You have three options if you want to pass it somewhere:

```
TC0_t timer = TCC0;
TC0_t *timer = &TCC0;
TC0_t *timer = (TC0_t*) 0x8000;
```

Keep in mind the first one will just copy current value. The other two should work exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define TCC0 (*(TC0_t*) 0x8000);
```

This is a macro definition. When you use it in your program, the text `TCC0` gets replaced with `(*(TC0_t*) 0x8000);`. For instance:

```
xtimer.timer = TCC0;
```

becomes:

```
xtimer.timer = (*(TC0_t*) 0x8000);;
```

(Note the double semi-colons. You should (probably) never add a trailing semi-colon in a macro definition.)

The constant `0x8000` is converted to a pointer of type `TC0_t *` yielding an implementation-defined result. This pointer is then dereferenced resulting in a value of type `TC0_t` (retrieved from the address 0x8000).

In your code, `xtimer.timer` is of type `TC0_t *`, so this is clearly an error (assuming that `TCD0` is a typo for `TCC0`).

It seems to me that you want either:

```
xtimer.timer = &TCC0;
```

or:

```
#define TCC0 ((TC0_t*) 0x8000)
```

There is no pointer to pointer anywhere in your code.

Comment: No, TCC0 and TCD0 are two different macro definitions at different addresses. They represent the timer of PORTC and PORTD of the microcontroller.

Comment: @Lpaulson: Right. It doesn't change the essence of the code though.